# vapor 3, fluent model doesn't create raw in DB

Tags: vapor

I am trying to create a model (`MySQLStringModel`)  and set an id(of `String ?` type) to it. There is no errors or any other message in console, and `save(on: req)` works successfully , but model doesn't appear in Table of the database.  Whats can be wrong?

```
func create(_ req: Request, person: Person) throws -> Future<Person> {
    return Person(id: person.id, name: person.name).save(on: req)
}
```

**P.s.**: All works when I use  MySQLModel with  `Int?` id, and I don't set this id directly (it sets automatic with autoincreament )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem in method
`.save(on: req)`

As said in the documentation:
`Saves the model, calling either create(...) or update(...) depending on whether the model already has an ID.`
`If you need to create a model with a pre-existing ID, call create instead.`

So, method `.create(on: req)` helped me, and new raw appeared in the table.

Comment: Note: `save(…)` as currently implemented is consisent with the Vapor documentation… however `save(…)` has two unexpected limitations. [1] no error or feedback is given that the instance was not actually written to the database. [2] `save(…)` makes a create(…) or update(…) solely based on the state of the Swift-side (without consideration of the actual state of the dabase.) Ideally, IMHO, `save(…)` or similar would be more aware and provide behaviour like SQL `UPDATE OR INSERT` or `UPSERT`. see [https://github.com/vapor/fluent-sqlite/issues/23](https://github.com/vapor/fluent-sqlite/issues/23)